# One time pad encryptions in java

Tags: java, arrays, list, encryption, random

I've create a one time pad encryption in java but I have two problems which are :

1. In Encryption, how can I can make the size of the key flexible according to the size of the plaintext and generated randomly for example , the size of the plaintext is 4 letters so the size of the array key must be 32-bit, because each letter has 8-bit.
2. In Decryption, how can I read from to files and these two files in binary form and then do XOR between them then print it as ASCLL form.

---

My code:

```
public class onetimepad {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        int[] key = generate8BitKey();

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(" One Time Pad encryption and decryption ");
        System.out.println(" For encryption Enter 1 ");
        System.out.println(" For decryption Enter 2 ");
        System.out.println(" Exit Enter 3 ");
        int a = in.nextInt();

        switch (a) {
            case 1:

                File input = new File("message.txt");
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(input);
                String msg = sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Key:    ");

                //Write the Key in file.
                PrintWriter writer2 = new PrintWriter("Output.txt", "UTF-8");
                writer2.println("------ Key ------- ");
                for (int i : key) {

                    System.out.print(key[i]);
                    writer2.print(key[i]);

                }
                writer2.close();

                System.out.println();
                String ciphertext = encrypt(msg, key);
                System.out.println("Encrypted Message: " + ciphertext);
                 break;
            case 2:
                 File input2 = new File("ciphertext.txt");
                Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(input2);
                String msg2 = sc2.nextLine();
                File input3 = new File("Key.txt");
                Scanner sc3 = new Scanner(input3);
                String msg3 = sc2.nextLine();


                 System.out.println("Decrypted Message: " + decrypt(msg3, key));
                break;
            default:
        }

    }// End the main.

    //------------------- Methods.
    public static String encrypt(String msg, int[] key) {
        int[] binmsg = stringToBinary(msg);
        int[] result = xor(binmsg, repeatArray(key, msg.length()));
        String r = "";
        for (int i : result) {
            r += (char) (result[i] + '0');
        }

        return r;
    }

    //---------------------
    public static String decrypt(String ciphertext, int[] key) {
        int[] bin = new int[ciphertext.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < ciphertext.length(); i++) {
            bin[i] = ciphertext.charAt(i) - '0';
        }
       int[] result = xor(bin, repeatArray(key, bin.length / 8));
        return binaryToString(result);
    }

    //---------------------
    public static int[] stringToBinary(String msg) {
        int[] result = new int[msg.length() * 8];
        for (int i = 0; i < msg.length(); i++) {
            String bin = Integer.toBinaryString((int) msg.charAt(i));
            while (bin.length() < 8) {
                bin = "0" + bin;
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < bin.length(); j++) {
                result[i * 8 + j] = bin.charAt(j) - '0';
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    //---------------------
    public static String binaryToString(int[] bin) {
        String result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < bin.length / 8; i++) {
            String c = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                c += (char) (bin[i * 8 + j] + '0');
            }
            result += (char) Integer.parseInt(c, 2);
        }
        return result;
    }

    //---------------------
    public static int[] generate8BitKey() {
        int[] key = new int[8];
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();
            key[i] = sr.nextInt(2);
        }
        return key;
    }

    //---------------------
    public static int[] xor(int[] a, int[] b) {
        int[] result = new int[a.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            result[i] = a[i] == b[i] ? 0 : 1;
        }
        return result;
    }

   //---------------------
   public static int[] repeatArray(int[] a, int n) {
        int[] result = new int[a.length * n];
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            result[i] = a[i % a.length];  // mod 
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: A one-time pad is a truly random sequence. The RNG's in a computer do not provide one-time-pads. What you have created is a stream cipher.

Comment: I believe you should not create a new instance of `SecureRandom` every time you fetch 8 bits. It is slow and maybe not even safer.

Comment: Is it a requirement to store each and every bit in a 32 bit integer? It seems more logical to use *one byte* for each 8 bits. In that case, the answer of Q1 is: return a byte array of a specific size. Similarly, you could just encrypt / decrypt the bytes within the files using `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream`, answering Q2.

Answer (score 2):

First - try to rewrite your application to use correct data types, meaning you would work on `byte[]` type with bits as bits.  Then it's easy to read, write, xor, encode, decode. Without it there are very few people who will attempt to understand your own constructs. So I will further assume you will do that.

Next - there's really no point of implementing own encoding operations (e.g. stringToBinary), look for simple ways to encode your data to hex or base64. For Hex you may use `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex`, for Base64 you already have already `java.util.Base64` class. It will be much more readable for you and anyone willing to help

> In Encryption, how can I can make the size of the key flexible according to the size of the plaintext and generated randomly for example , the size of the plaintext is 4 letters so the size of the array key must be 32-bit, because each letter has 8-bit.

Assuming that you have finally rewritten your application to work on byte arrays, you may write

```
SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();
byte[] keyBytes = new bytes[4];
sr.nextBytes (keyBytes);
```

That will generate 4 bytes with high entropy. However - there is an issue with the whole approach:

- To decrypt the data you will need to store the key of length of the message and you may use the key only once with a single message (that's feature of the one time pad).
- Imagine you have much longer message, say - in kilobytes.  SecureRandom may be very slow to generate key of arbitrary (longer) length or it may produce not really random data. Long story short - that's why PRNGs are used (often I see ChaCha or Salsa20 stream cipher used as PRNG) to generate arbitrary length of randomly looking data from initial key.

> In Decryption, how can I read from to files and these two files in binary form and then do XOR between them then print it as ASCLL form.

Once you rewrite your application to use `byte[]` types, then (as Maarten already commented) you have FileInputStream and FileOutputStream to your disposal (and it's easy to XOR bytes `a ^ b` )